# While generating dashboard report in Jmeter, Unnecessary filter is showing and therefor pass api list is not showing

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

When I try to generate the dashboard report,I am hitting 2 API, the list of pass API is not showing and the Unnecessary filter is showing [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something you defined somewhere, check the following files:

- jmeter.properties
- user.properties
- reportgenerator.properties
- whatever custom .properties file you have

for the `jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter` entry, it should be there with the filter you defined. Just comment out or remove the line and you will start seeing all the requests in the dashboard.

More information:

- [Reporting Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thank you very much Dmitri. I have commented jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter this in user.properties

Answer (score 0):

comment jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter this in user.properties then generate the report.